# Can someone help me spot the error in my sql syntax here?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a syntax error I'm having trouble discerning. Help appreciated!

> Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '`i_id` int,     PRIMARY KEY (d_id),     FOREIGN KEY
>   (i_id) REFERENCES Indicators (i_id' at line 6:

```
CREATE TABLE Indicators
(
    `i_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `i_name` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (i_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Data
(
    `d_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Year` year,
    `Datapoint` float(24,2)
    `i_id` int,
    PRIMARY KEY (d_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (i_id) REFERENCES Indicators (i_id)
);
```

Comment: Are those really backticks, or are they actually apostrophes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the comma at the end of the `Datapoint` line

Also if the default engine of your MySQL instance is not `InnoDB` you will not be able to create the foreign keys.

Comment: Booyah! Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
    `d_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Year` year,
    `Datapoint` float(24,2),
                           ^------ here it is
    `i_id` int,
    PRIMARY KEY (d_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (i_id) REFERENCES Indicators (i_id)
);
```

you're missing a comma after `float(24,2)`